# Android Contact Groups

Tags: android, android-contacts

I had business requirement to add,modify,delete contact through xml in the background and show it on native UI of address book. I am able to add only single groups but not able to associate the existing contacts to the group.Can any one suggest and solution to it.

Thanks,
Alok Singh